# Ansible: selecting dict element by extra var

Tags: dictionary, ansible

I am trying to create a playbook to set up log collecting daemons. I have a dict with the parameters to set up (used in templates). Someting like this

```yaml
logservers:
  prod:
    ipaddress: 10.10.44.79
    envname: "Productive servers"
    other_data: "important prod data"
  test:
    ipaddress: 10.20.44.79
    envname: "Testing servers"
    other_data: "data for testing"
  dev:
    ipaddress: 10.30.44.79
    envname: "Developement servers"
    other_data: "developers data"
```

Is it possible to use an extra var, like `-e env=prod` on running the playbook and use this tho select "prod" element from the dict when templating?

Or, what is the method to achieve this in Ansible?

And a last bit: I would need this for a fairly old dist of Ansible to work on (2.4)

Comment: <code>
logservers:
  prod:
    ipaddress: 10.10.44.79
    envname: "Productive servers"
    other_data: "important prod data"
  test:
    ipaddress: 10.20.44.79
    envname: "Testing servers"
    other_data: "data for testing"
  dev:
    ipaddress: 10.30.44.79
    envname: "Developement servers"
    other_data: "developers data"
</code>

Comment: Please do not add necessary information to answer your question in comments. [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70642819/edit) your question instead. Meanwhile the answer to your question is trivial => `{{ logsservers[env].ipaddress }}`, `{{ logsservers[env].envname }}`, etc. See https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#referencing-nested-variables and https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/faq.html#when-should-i-use-also-how-to-interpolate-variables-or-dynamic-variable-names as a start.

Comment: @Trifo dont forget to close your question by validating/upvoting the right answer.. it is the way to say thanks to stackoverflow helpers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there are lot of ways to do that:

one way is to use a new variable `server` which has the data wanted following the extra var:

```
- name: configure app servers
  hosts: localhost
  vars:
    logservers:
      prod:
        ipaddress: 10.10.44.79
        envname: "Productive servers"
        other_data: "important prod data"
      test:
        ipaddress: 10.20.44.79
        envname: "Testing servers"
        other_data: "data for testing"
      dev:
        ipaddress: 10.30.44.79
        envname: "Developement servers"
        other_data: "developers data"

    server: "{{ logservers[env] }}"

  tasks:
    - name: display "{{ env }}"
      debug:
        msg: "{{ server }}"
```

you launch the playbook:

```
ansible-playbook play.yml -e env=dev
```

result:

```
TASK [display "dev"] ****************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": {
        "envname": "Developement servers",
        "ipaddress": "10.30.44.79"
        "other_data": "developers data"
    }
}
```

---

you launch the playbook:

```
ansible-playbook play.yml -e env=prod
```

result:

```
TASK [display "prod"] ***************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": {
        "envname": "Productive servers",
        "ipaddress": "10.10.44.79"
        "other_data": "important prod data"
    }
}
```